# Php - optimizing multiple counter increments

Tags: php, optimization, query-optimization

On a very heavy traffic LAMP server I'm using a memory table to keep track of several data items as counters. It is implemented like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO daily_info_mem SET di_num=1 ,di_type=9, di_date = current_date(), di_sid= $sid_int ,di_name='user_counter' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE di_num=di_num+1";
```

The index sets unique di_type and date, so if the counter exists for this date then di_type it is incremented, if not a row for this date and data type is created  with 0 value.

There are several such queries for each page view. Which means several mysql calls.

Is it possible to optimize this as much as possible into one mysql call that will update several arbitrary counters and still keep the idea of creating the row if needed or increasing the vale if it exists?

Comment: Why don't you use auto-increment, stuff like that, to handle your counter ?

Comment: If I'm correct, auto increment is for index values on row level. I'm incrementing a field, not the number of rows

Comment: Do you mean "counter" fields within the same row? Like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE di_num=di_num+1, c2=c2+99, c3=c3+47 ?

Comment: yes. please see the code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend re-thinking this type of query entirely. You're hitting your primary database a lot there for something which could be better handled in-memory. Is it absolutely required to update MySQL instantly every time? If you can get it out of MySQL and into memcached you'll see a huge performance bump, and you can always have a script running in the background to collate the data and push it to MySQL regularly (say, every 5 mins) so you don't loose anything.

If it absolutely must be inside MySQL, you might be better off using a HEAP table rather than an InnoDB table. You'll loose your "on duplicate key" but you could always use a stored procedure/function to do the update. And again, you can always have a scheduled query/timed script to "INSERT INTO... SELECT FROM..." to an `archive`-type table so you don't loose anything.

Or, use a completely different database for storing your stats. MongoDB has `upsert`s and `$inc`rements which makes it a very good choice for statistic gathering.

Comment: Thanks! 
The table this works on is a memory table. I'm updating the non-memory table every 15 mins period.

Comment: Then I suspect you've hit the limit of what mysql can provide you; mysql is a great little database, but its not the right choice for everything. Memcached or MongoDB would be a better fit in this instance.